# json data formatting using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here, having the input data in this format (json) :

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": "2019-05-25T00:00:00",
        "name": "sample_name",
        "keys": ["Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3", "Field 4", "Field 5", "Field 6"],
        "values": ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", "value6"],
        "is_accepted": false,
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "2018-05-26T00:00:00",
        "name": "sample_name",
        "keys": ["Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3", "Field 4", "Field 5", "Field 6"],
        "values": ["value11", "value21", "value31", "value41", "value51", "value61"],
        "is_accepted": false,
    }
]
```

and I need to reformat it as per the following

```
{
    "info": {
        "timeColumn": "date",
        "name": "sample_name",
        "segments": ["Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3", "Field 4", "Field 5", "Field 6"]
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "Field 1": "value1",
            "Field 2": "value2",
            "Field 3": "value3",
            "Field 4": "value4",
            "Field 5": "value5",
            "Field 6": "value6",
            "date": "2019-05-25T00:00:00",
            "is_accepted": false
        },
        {
            "Field 1": "value11",
            "Field 2": "value21",
            "Field 3": "value31",
            "Field 4": "value41",
            "Field 5": "value51",
            "Field 6": "value61",
            "date": "2018-05-26T00:00:00",
            "is_accepted": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Need to combine the values into the data field from the input json data. Since I'm a newbie in coding, is there any effective approach that can be adopted here using pandas

Comment: Why do you want to use pandas?

Comment: @richardec thanks in advance, can you suggest an approach that can be used for the processing of this json

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Python here to reformat your json file, like this:

```py
# Define a helper function
def reformat(input_item):
    output_item = {
        key: value for key, value in zip(input_item["keys"], input_item["values"])
    }
    output_item["date"] = input_item["timestamp"]
    output_item["is_accepted"] = input_item["is_accepted"]
    return output_item

# Build a new dictionary
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

new_data = {
    "info": {
        "timeColumn": "date",
        "name": "sample_name",
        "segments": ["Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3", "Field 4", "Field 5", "Field 6"],
    },
    "data": [reformat(input_item) for input_item in data],
}

# Save to a new json file
with open("new_data.json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(new_data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

In `new_data.json`, you find the expected result:

```json
{
    "info": {
        "timeColumn": "date",
        "name": "sample_name",
        "segments": [
            "Field 1",
            "Field 2",
            "Field 3",
            "Field 4",
            "Field 5",
            "Field 6"
        ]
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "Field 1": "value1",
            "Field 2": "value2",
            "Field 3": "value3",
            "Field 4": "value4",
            "Field 5": "value5",
            "Field 6": "value6",
            "date": "2019-05-25T00:00:00",
            "is_accepted": "false"
        },
        {
            "Field 1": "value11",
            "Field 2": "value21",
            "Field 3": "value31",
            "Field 4": "value41",
            "Field 5": "value51",
            "Field 6": "value61",
            "date": "2018-05-26T00:00:00",
            "is_accepted": "false"
        }
    ]
}
```